# How do you set CacheMode on an element programmatically?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

Silverlight 3 introduced the `CacheMode` parameter on elements. Currently the only supported format is `BitmapCache`. In XAML this value can set as the following:

```
<Image CacheMode="BitmapCache" Source="MyImage.png"></Image>
```

I would like to do the same thing at runtime but have failed so far, neither of the following examples work

```
Image image;
image.CacheMode = ?? // Could not find any enum to set it to
image.CacheMode.SetValue(CacheModeProperty, "BitmapCache"); // Does not work
```

I'm looking for someone to provide code or workaround for dynamically creating an element (e.g. `Image`) and setting its `CacheMode` to `BitmapCache`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think the property value of CacheMode is an enum, I think its an abstract class.

So you should have something like:

```
image.CacheMode = new BitmapCache();
```

There might even be a static instance of BitmapCache somewhere (like on CacheMode).

And yes, having an abstract class called ~Mode is a bit weird imo ;)